# Expected value inside a utility function

Tags: econometrics, expected-utility

Lets say Agent 1 has a utility function that depends on the other person, i.e.,  $u_1(x_1-x_2)$, where $x_i$ is the choice of Agent $i$. Suppose the expected value of $x_2$ is denoted $E[x_2]$.

Can $u_1(x_1-E[x_2])$ be defined as Agent 1's expected utility from choosing some $x_1$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, $u_1(x_1-E[x_2])$ is agent $1$'s *utility of the expected value*, not the *expected utility of the value*.

Generally $u(E(x)) \neq E(u(x))$. A simple example:

Let $x$ take value $-1$ with probability $50\%$ and value $1$ with probability $50\%$. Let $u(x) = x^2$. Then
$$E(x) = 50\% \cdot (-1) + 50\% \cdot 1 = 0$$
$$u(E(x)) = 0^2 = 0$$
$$E(u(x)) = 50\% \cdot (-1)^2 + 50\% \cdot 1 = 1$$

There are special cases where $u(E(x)) = E(u(x))$ does hold, e.g., this is always true when $u$ is an affine function. The equality never holds when $u$ is strictly convex, see [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality).